# PHP: Converting WP_ERROR to Exception

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently struggling to add error handling for the following case. An error is raise when a `$db` database is trying to write into it when it has `--read-only` access. This causes the following error on WP Engine.

```
WordPress database error INSERT command denied to user 'readonly'@'xx.xxx.xx.xx' for table 'responses' for query INSERT INTO `responses`
```

I wan't for this error to not break the application so I'm trying to add error handling. However, when I raise an Exception is not being caught. I know that `WP_ERROR` are different, so how to I convert an `WP_ERROR` to an exception?

```
function drools_request($data, $uid) {
  try {
    $db = _get_db();
    $insertion = $db->insert("requests", [
      "uid" => $uid,
      "data" => json_encode($data),
    ]);
    if( is_wp_error($insertion) ) {
      throw new \Exception('Error writing to the database:');
    }
  }
  catch(\Exception $e)
  {
    echo 'Error writing to the database: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  }
}
```

This is what I tried so far without success. Here I check for `is_wp_error()` if this condition is true I throw an exception. However, this did not work. I thought this is how one would go about handling a `WP_ERROR`, but I wonder if there is another way to handle this type of errors. Here is the full class:

```
<?php

namespace StatCollector;

function drools_request($data, $uid) {
  try {
    $db = _get_db();
    $insertion = $db->insert("requests", [
      "uid" => $uid,
      "data" => json_encode($data),
    ]);
    if( is_wp_error($insertion) ) {
      throw new \Exception('Error writing to the database:');
    }
  }
  catch(\Exception $e)
  {
    echo 'Error writing to the database: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  }
}

function drools_response($response, $uid) {
  try {
    $db = _get_db();
    $insertion = $db->insert("responses", [
      "uid" => $uid,
      "data" => json_encode($response),
    ]);
    if( is_wp_error($insertion) ) {
      throw new \Exception('Error writing to the database:');
    }
  }
  catch(\Exception $e)
  {
    echo 'Error writing to the database: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  }
}

function results_sent($type, $to, $uid, $url = null, $message = null) {
  try {
    $db = _get_db();
    $insertion = $db->insert("messages", [
      "uid" => $uid,
      "msg_type" => strtolower($type),
      "address" => $to,
      "url" => $url,
      "message" => $message
    ]);
    if( is_wp_error($insertion) ) {
      throw new \Exception('Error writing to the database:');
    }
  }
  catch(\Exception $e)
  {
    echo 'Error writing to the database: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  }
}

function peu_data($staff, $client, $uid) {
  try {
    if (empty($uid)) {
      return;
    }
    $db = _get_db();

    if (! empty($staff)) {
      $insertion = $db->insert("peu_staff", [
        "uid" => $uid,
        "data" => json_encode($staff)
      ]);
    }
    if( is_wp_error( $insertion ) ) {
      throw new \Exception('Error writing to the database:');
    }
    if (! empty($client)) {
      $insertion = $db->insert("peu_client", [
        "uid" => $uid,
        "data" => json_encode($client)
      ]);
    }
    if( is_wp_error($insertion) ) {
      throw new \Exception('Error writing to the database:');
    }
  }
  catch(\Exception $e){
    echo 'Error writing to the database: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  }
}


function response_update() {
  $uid = $_POST['GUID'];
  $url = $_POST['url'];
  $programs = $_POST['programs'];
  if (empty($uid) || empty($url) || empty($programs)) {
    wp_send_json(["status" => "fail","message" => "missing values"]);
    return wp_die();
  }

  try {
    $db = _get_db();
    $insertion = $db->insert("response_update", [
      "uid" => $uid,
      "url" => $url,
      "program_codes" => $programs
    ]);
    wp_send_json(["status" => "ok"]);
    wp_die();
    if( is_wp_error($insertion) ) {
      throw new \Exception('Error writing to the database.');
    }
  }
  catch(\Exception $e)
  {
    echo 'Error writing to the database: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wpdb::insert` does not return WP_Error on error. On error it returns boolean `false`.  The error printing is done inside of `wpdb::query` itself, but you can disable that by setting `suppress_errors` to true, and then gracefully get the previous error with the `last_error` property.

```
$db->suppress_errors(true);
//Note: If you still want to log the errors to your server log
//use $db->hide_errors(); instead.
$insertion = $db->insert("requests", [
  "uid" => $uid,
  "data" => json_encode($data),
]);
if( $insertion === false ) {
  throw new \Exception('Error writing to the database: ' . $db->last_error);
}
```